# Allowing apache to access /home/user directory

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have a text file at `/home/user/textdata` that user change it everyday
and I have a PHP script at `/var/www/` that want to read that text file.

How to add the permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `chmod o+rwx /home/user/textdata`

Comment: still access denied

Comment: fixed by `chmod o+x /home/user`